# Finding most recent entry in a meteor collection

Tags: meteor

My task sounds simple, but I can't nail down how to write this... I simply want to find the most recent item inserted into a collection and display it on my meteor app.

I've been playing with Collection.find() with no real results. This is the last line I've tried: (keep in mind these names are placeholder. My collection is not called Collection in my code)

> ```
> Template.tempname.tempitem = function () {
>     return Collection.find({}, {sort: {DateTime: -1, limit: 1,}});
> };
> ```

I have a feild in the collection that is the result of

> Date.parse(Date())

which should allow me to sort by most recent. There is likely other ways to do this, but this was the first solution I came up with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#findone) you can also do:

```
return Collection.findOne({}, {sort: {DateTime: -1, limit: 1}});
```

Provided that `DateTime` is this field that you do `Date.parse(Date())`. Also you don't have to store dates as unix timestamps you can just do `new Date()` and it would be stored as the `Date` object type.

Comment: Ah i understand now. That works great. I'll likely change how i store the date since that seems to make the most sense. I wasn't sure how the sorting would work with a normal date.

Comment: Why limit: 1 while using findOne ?

Comment: @elhoucine At the time of this post it was required to pass a parameter for `limit` alongside `sort`. Using `findOne` is an alias for `find().fetch()[0]` (this is not `find` with a `limit` of 1 and wasn't wasn't using `limit` in the query at the time. I'm not sure if this is different today, it may be the same.

Comment: In Meteor 1.2.1 I can make the call without 'limit' on the client, FYI

Comment: What about performance ? Is there a more efficient solution or is that the best we can do ?

Answer (score 0):

I could only get the desired result by doing

```
let commentsTmp: Comment = Comments.findOne({ parentId: this.currentPost._id }, { sort: { time: -1 } });
```

with `MongoObservable.Collection<T>`

Hope this will help someone.