# How would I go about returning only the newest result in return helper

Tags: meteor

My terminology may not exactly be correct, however I am trying to figure out how to return only the most recent post in a collection. I currently can return all of them with the following code

JS

```
Template.motionPictures.helpers({
  ownPost: function() {
    return this.userId == Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

JS

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{> filmItem}}
  {{/each}}
```

HTML

```
{{message}}
```

How would i modify the template helper to return just the most recent {{message}} instead of all of them?

UPDATE

I have tried the following, however it is still showing all the posts instead of limiting it to 1.

```
Template.motionPictures.helpers({
  posts: function() {
    return Posts.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1, limit: 1}});
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding most recent entry in a meteor collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980759/finding-most-recent-entry-in-a-meteor-collection)

Comment: @davidweldon Im having a little trouble using this question to work with my setup, anyway you could help me with my particular case.

Comment: where do you define `posts`? It should not be a helper, but simply data in the context of your template. Also, what the relevance of `ownPost`, you don't seem to use it in your code, so why do you show us that helper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using a helper where you shouldn't and clearly there is a typo in your `find` (limit was in sort). Try this:

```
Template.motionPictures.posts = function() {
    return Posts.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: 1});
};
```

Comment: And: shouldn't it be `Posts.findOne()`?