# How to get the value of the last item in a Mongo collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I read a Mongo collection and I want to get the value of the last item. I do a method to sort from oldest to newest ([stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23982699/6864454)) and take only the first item but I can't get his value.

This is the code where I insert data in the collection:

```
'container.start': function(id) {
    var ctn = docker.getContainer(id);
    ctn.start(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, data) {
      if(err){
        ErrorsContainer.upsert({

        }, {
            error: err
        });
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log(data);
      }
    }));
}
```

Then the code where I read the collection:

```
  'click .start'(event) {
      const idDB = this._id
      const container = InfosContainers.findOne({_id: idDB});
      const name =  container["nameContainer"];
      const idContainer = container["idContainer"];
      console.log("the container: " + name + " is going to be started. His id is: " + idContainer);
      Meteor.call("container.start",idContainer);
      //get the last error
      var error = ErrorsContainer.find({}, {sort: {_id: 1, limit: 1}});
      if(error){
        alert(error[error]); //tried error.error too
      }
  }
```

So how could I get the value of collection's error ?

Comment: {sort: {_id: 1, limit: 1}} should be {sort: {_id: 1}, limit: 1}

Comment: The thing was the collection's error was containing others object ! So look my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was that collection's error was containing others things and I had to do it like this:

```
  var lastError = ErrorsContainer.findOne({}, {sort: {_id: 1}});
  console.log(lastError.error.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

do

```
{ sort: { created : -1 } }
```

where created is the created time of the document
and -1 is for sorting in DEC ordre (1 for sorting in INC order)